# How to reuse a multiprocessing pool?

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

At the bottom is the code I have now. It seems to work fine. However, I don't completely understand it. I thought without `.join()`, I'd risking the code going onto the next for-loop before the pool finishes executing. Wouldn't we need those 3 commented-out lines?

On the other hand, if I were to go with the `.close()` and `.join()` way, is there any way to 'reopen' that closed pool instead of `Pool(6)` every time?

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import random as rdm
from statistics import stdev, mean
import time


def mesh_subset(population, n_chosen=5):
    chosen = rdm.choices(population, k=n_chosen)
    return mean(chosen)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    population = [x for x in range(20)]
    N_iteration = 10
    start_time = time.time()
    pool = mp.Pool(6)
    for i in range(N_iteration):
        print([round(x,2) for x in population])
        print(stdev(population))
        # pool = mp.Pool(6)
        population = pool.map(mesh_subset, [population]*len(population))
        # pool.close()
        # pool.join()
    print('run time:', time.time() - start_time)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A pool of workers is a relatively costly thing to set up, so it should be done (if possible) only once, usually at the beginning of the script.

The `pool.map` command blocks until all the tasks are completed. After all, it returns a list of the results. It couldn't do that unless `mesh_subset` has been called on all the inputs and has returned a result for each. In contrast, methods like `pool.apply_async` do not block. `apply_async` returns an ApplyResult object with a `get` method which blocks until it obtains a result from a worker process.

`pool.close` [sets the worker handler's state](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#L565) to CLOSE. This causes the handler to [signal the workers](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#L441) to terminate.

The `pool.join` blocks until all the worker processes have been terminated.

So you don't need to call -- in fact you shouldn't call -- `pool.close` and `pool.join` until you are finished with the pool. Once the workers have been sent the signal to terminate (by `pool.close`), there is no way to "reopen" them. You would need to start a new pool instead.

---

In your situation, since you *do* want the loop to wait until all the tasks are completed, there would be no advantage to using `pool.apply_async` instead of `pool.map`. But if you were to use `pool.apply_async`, you could obtain the same result as before by calling `get` instead of resorting to closing and restarting the pool:

```
# you could do this, but using pool.map is simpler
for i in range(N_iteration):
    apply_results = [pool.apply_async(mesh_subset, [population]) for i in range(len(population))]
    # the call to result.get() blocks until its worker process (running
    # mesh_subset) returns a value
    population = [result.get() for result in apply_results]
```

When the loops complete, `len(population)` is unchanged.

---

If you did NOT want each loop to block until all the tasks are completed, you could use `apply_async`'s `callback` feature:

```
N_pop = len(population)
result = []
for i in range(N_iteration):
    for i in range(N_pop):
        pool.apply_async(mesh_subset, [population]),
                         callback=result.append)
pool.close()
pool.join()
print(result)
```

Now, when any `mesh_subset` returns a `return_value`,
`result.append(return_value)` is called.  The calls to `apply_async` do not
block, so `N_iteration * N_pop` tasks are pushed into the `pool`s task
queue all at once. But since the pool has 6 workers, at most 6 calls to
`mesh_subset` are running at any given time. As the workers complete the tasks,
whichever worker finishes first calls `result.append(return_value)`. So the
values in `result` are unordered.  This is different than `pool.map` which
returns a list whose return values are in the same order as its corresponding
list of arguments.

Barring an exception, `result` will eventually contain `N_iteration * N_pop` return values *once
all the tasks complete*.  Above, `pool.close()` and `pool.join()` were used to
wait for all the tasks to complete.

Comment: Thanks, @unutbu, Just try to test if I understand it: so, had I used `pool.wait_async`, but still didn't want the code to go beyond a certain line before all processes finish running, then I would need to do `pool.close` and `pool.join`, in which case, I do need to reconstruct the pool with `pool = mp.Pool(6)` in each loop?

Comment: I added some code an explanation showing how one might use `pool.apply_async` *without* calling `pool.close()` and `pool.join()` each time through the loop.

Comment: Why would `population` eventually contain `N_iteration * len(population)` values? In my code (and intention), the size of population wouldn't change after each iteration. What each iteration does is: draw a few (default to 5, see my edit) and take average to form one member of the new population, repeat this drawing until the new population has the same size as the current population.

Comment: Sorry -- there was a mistake in the code I posted.  Each call to
`pool.apply_async(func)` is like a single call to `func` (except that it happens
in a separate process.) Thus, the analog of a single call to `pool.map` is a
for-loop of calls to `pool.apply_async`.

Comment: Given the intent of your code, it's clear `pool.apply_async` is not the right tool for the job.
I hope the code I added helps explain *how* `pool.apply_async` is used in general, even if it is not useful for your current project.

Comment: Thanks, accepted answer since it addresses my original question. Just curious though, as the callback changes `population` each time, does each `mesh_subset` take the original `population` or the changed `population` whenever the job is pushed into the pool?

Comment: I changed the code above so the callback now calls `result.append` instead of `population.append` -- to avoid the race condition using `population.append` would cause. It would have been possible for `mesh_subset` to receive a changed `population`.

Comment: suggested an edit to the answer to reflect what I want exactly here, however, not sure if `result` needs to be a shared Array or it needs to be deep copied to population at the bottom of each outer for-loop

Comment: I saw your suggested edit, but had to reject it because it would not have worked as intended. Since `pool.apply_async` does not block, calling `population = result` could assign `population` to a partial or empty list.

Comment: That makes sense. Is there any way to achieve what I want without duplicating the input with `[population]*len(population)` like I did in the question?

Comment: `[population]*len(population)` makes `len(population)` *references* to the same object, `population`. So even if `population` is huge, a list of references to that huge object is not in itself very huge. So I wouldn't worry about.

Comment: Note that the multiprocessing package implements interprocess communication via queues. The queues pickle the inputs and transfer the data (the name of the function and its arguments)  as bytes through a pipe. If the arguments (such as `population`) are huge, then pickling / interprocess communication takes time, which reduces the effectiveness of multiprocessing. Moreover, if the worker process is very quick, such as merely calling `random.choice`, then the cost of interprocess communication becomes very expensive relative to the minor advantage obtained by using multiple processes.

Comment: The moral of the story is: The key to speed with multiprocessing is to make the workers do a lot of work and as little interprocess communication as possible. If the workers do little work (that is, the function ends quickly) and there is a lot of interprocess communication, then your multiprocessing code may be slower than a single process serial version of the computation.

Comment: awesome, thanks! another upvote comment, this really helps me as a newbee to parallel computing.