# Is it better to have one Pool for more functions in Python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm using `multiprocessing.Pool` in 2 function that run sequentially. I create the `Pool` in the first function and when it terminate, I close it and open it in the second.

Ex.

```
def first_function():
   pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
   .
   .
   pool.join()
   pool.close()

def second_function():
   pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
   .
   .
   pool.join()
   pool.close()
```

Is it more efficient to create one single `Pool` before the 2 functions start and then pass it like argument?

Comment: What is actually happening in those functions? Usually you create a `Pool` and ***pass the functions as an argument***, not the other way around...

Comment: There is overhead in spawning processes, so creating multiple pools _likely_ carries some drawback, but it's also _unlikely_ to be significant.  You could always test both implementations.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53911991/how-to-reuse-a-multiprocessing-pool).

Comment: @Tomerikoo It is a Flask server that receive images from front-end. I call the first_function for convert the images to jpeg and then I call the second function to perform calculations and create models. In order to speed-up I do it in multi-processing like in the example I posted, but I think is worth to create one single pool which executes both functions.